# Putting the value in ConcurrentHashMap is atomic or not?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I am working on a project in which I am making connections to database. And I need to see how many times an `exception is happening` if there are any. I am working with `Multithreaded code`, meaning multiple threads will be making connection to database and inserting into database. So it might be possible that at some point connection get lost so we need to see how many times those exception has occurred.

So I wrote a below code and in the catch block, I am catching exception and making a counter to increased every time if there is any exeption and putting it in `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
class Task implements Runnable {

     public static final AtomicInteger counter_sql_exception = new AtomicInteger(0);
     public static final AtomicInteger counter_exception = new AtomicInteger(0);
     public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> exceptionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

     @Override
     public void run() {

     try {

         //Make a db connection and then executing the SQL-

         } catch (SQLException e) {
              synchronized(this) {
                   exceptionMap.put(e.getCause().toString(), counter_sql_exception.incrementAndGet());
              }
              LOG.Error("Log Exception")
          } catch (Exception e) {
              synchronized(this) {
                   exceptionMap.put(e.getCause().toString(), counter_exception.incrementAndGet());
              }
              LOG.Error("Log Exception")
        }
      }
  }
```

**My Question is-** Today I had a code review and one of my senior team members said, you won't be needing `synchronized(this)` on the `exceptionMap` in the `catch block`. I said yes we will be needing because incrementing the counter is atomic. Putting a new value in the map is atomic. But doing both without synchronization is not atomic . And he said `ConurrentHashMap` will be doing this for you.

So does I will be needing `synchronized(this)` block on that `exceptionMap` or not.? If not then why? And if Yes then what reason should I quote to him.

Comment: are you trying to count all the exceptions that are happening, or the number of times each exception happens?

Comment: Number of times each exception has happened.

Comment: then why are you using one, shared counter?

Comment: Sorry let me update my question for that. I am not using shared counter. When I posted question, by mistake I copied only counter.

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: Your transaction does need to be atomic, but your code does not accomplish this because you are synchronizing on the wrong monitor.

Comment: Yeah. That's what he also said to me. I was synchronizing on the wrong channel, then how should I synchronize?

Comment: @FarhanJamal - the easiest thing to do would be to synchronize on the class itself - `synchronized(Task.class)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are tying to count the number of times each exception occured, then you need something like this:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> exceptionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

private static void addException(String cause) {
  AtomicInteger count = exceptionMap.get(cause);
  if(count == null) {
    count = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger curCount = exception.putIfAbsent(cause, count);
    if(curCount != null) {
      count = curCount;
    }
  }
  count.incrementAndGet();
}
```

note that having a static map of exceptions is a resource leak unless you periodically clean it out.

As @dnault mentioned, you could also use [guava's AtomicLongMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html).

UPDATE: some comments on your original:

- you are correct, that you *do* need another wrapping synchronized block to ensure that the latest value actually makes it into the map.  however, as @Perception already pointed out in comments, you are synchronizing on the *wrong object instance* (since you are updating static maps, you need a static instance, such as `Task.class`)
- however, you are using a static counter, but a String key which could be different for different exceptions, thus you aren't actually counting each exception cause, but instead sticking random numbers in as various map values
- lastly, as i've shown in my example, you can solve the aforementioned issues and discard the synchronized blocks completely by making appropriate use of the ConcurrentMap.

Comment: Thanks jtahlborn for the suggestion. So that means I can put the above method call in the catch block right? `catch(Exception e) {
addException(e.getCause().toString());
}
` like this?

Comment: See Guava's AtomicLongMap.

Comment: @FarhanJamal - yes, that's how you would use it.

Comment: Thanks I will do that like this. One more thing, the way I am doing currently why my senior folks told me you won't be needing `synchronized(this)` ? Can you please explain me that just for the knowledge?

Comment: @FarhanJamal - technically, your version is wrong in a variety of ways, so it's hard to address that question specifically.

Comment: @FarhanJamal - added some comments detailing the problems in your example.

Comment: @FarhanJamal - actually, noticed a minor bug in my previous code example, please see the latest version.

Comment: There is one more bug I guess. Suppose if same exception has happened 20 times. Then the way your code is being written it will not update the map with that string exception and 20 times the value I guess. Something is missing for sure.

Comment: @FarhanJamal - it will certainly update the map with the count of 20.  notice i am storing the AtomicInteger _in the map_.

Comment: @FarhanJamal - it should be trivial to test the basic functionality of the map and confirm it works correctly.

Comment: Yeah I tested it out. Take a look at the first line. Count won't be null if that exception has happened second time. So the loop is not properly closed I guess, so that is the reason it won't increment the counter.

Comment: Yeah. One more thing I wanted to ask is, suppose if same exception has happened three times, then the map will have that string and total count of that exception but at the same time, suppose if another exception has happened two times, then how it gets decided that the count is going in right value pair of string?

Comment: @FarhanJamal - that's how maps work...  not sure what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

And this way should also work.

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> exceptionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

private static void addException(String cause) {
    Integer oldVal, newVal;
    do {
      oldVal = exceptionMap .get(cause);
      newVal = (oldVal == null) ? 1 : (oldVal + 1);
    } while (!queryCounts.replace(q, oldVal, newVal)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't allow null values, so `replace` will throw exception if called with `oldValue == null`. I used this code to increase counter by `delta` with returning `oldValue`.

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Integer,Integer> counters = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,Integer>();

private Integer counterAddDeltaAndGet(Integer key, Integer delta) {
    Integer oldValue = counters.putIfAbsent(key, delta);
    if(oldValue == null) return null;

    while(!counters.replace(key, oldValue, oldValue + delta)) {
        oldValue = counters.get(key);
    }

    return oldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `synchronized` block and `AtomicInteger`. You can do it just with `ConcurrentHashMap.compute` method which is a thread-safe atomic operation. So your code will look something like this

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

    public static final Map<String, Integer> EXCEPTION_MAP = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            // Make a db connection and then executing the SQL-

        } catch (Exception e) {
            EXCEPTION_MAP.compute(e.getCause().toString(), (key, value) -> {
                if (value == null) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return ++value;
            });
        }

    }

}
```